# Codeigniter update method not updating MYSQL records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm just learning how to program in codeigniter,I'm following a tutorial, my problem is that i want to update a MYSQL database with a method that calls a model and the model updates the database. But it doesn't i've tried different approaches to the model i can't seem to identify where the problem is:

1.i tried to code the model this way:

```
 `public function updateRecords($id, $name, $email, $password, $mobile)
         { 
            $query=$this->db->query("update users SET 
            name='$name',email='$email',mobile='$mobile' where user_id='".$id."'");
         }`
```

> but got this error: **Call to a member function result() on boolean in CodeIgniter, SQL**

2.i tried this way:

```
  public function updateRecords($id, $name, $email, $password, $mobile)
    {
        $data = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'passwords' => $password,
            'mobile' => $mobile
        );

        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('Users', $data, array('id' => $id));

    }
```

this above works but does not update records.

Here are the methods model and view of my current setup:

My current Controller:

```
public function updateData()
    {
        $this->load->model('Database');
        $id = $this->input->get('id');
        $result['data'] = $this->Database->displayRecordsById($id);
        $this->load->view('pages/edit', $result);
        if ($this->input->post('update')) {
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $mobile = $this->input->post('mobile');
            $this->Database->updateRecords($id, $name, $email, $password, $mobile);
            redirect('page/displaydata');
        }
    }
```

My current Model:

```
public function updateRecords($id, $name, $email, $password, $mobile)
    {
        $data = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'passwords' => $password,
            'mobile' => $mobile
        );

        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('Users', $data, array('id' => $id));
        

    enter code here
    }


public function displayRecordsById($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id='" . $id . "'");
        return $query->result();
    }
```

My current View:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
        }

        th {
            width: 200px;
            background-color: darkslateblue;
            color: snow;
            border-collapse: separate;
            margin: 0;


        }

        td {
            text-align: left;
            border-collapse: separate;
        }
    </style>
    <h3>Update User Information</h3>
    <?php echo form_open(); ?>
    <?php

    $i = 1;
    foreach ($data as $row) {


        echo form_input($data = '', $id = $row->id) . '<br/>';
        echo form_label('Name', 'user name') . '<br/>';
        echo form_input($data = '', $name = $row->name) . '<br/>';
        echo form_label('Email', 'email') . '<br/>';
        echo form_input($data = '', $email = $row->email) . '<br/>';
        echo form_label('Password', 'password') . '<br/>';
        echo form_input($data = '', $password = $row->passwords) . '<br/>';
        echo form_label('Mobile', 'user name') . '<br/>';
        echo form_input($data = '', $mobile = $row->mobile) . '<br/>';
        echo form_submit('update', 'Update');
    } ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>

</html>
```
````

Comment: Your `query(` usages are open to SQL injections. You should not use that approach. Your second approach is better. I think just `, array('id' => $id)` should be removed because the `where` does that and the `'id' => $id,` should be removed from the `$data` array because that's not going to change (although it wouldn't really do anything since you'd be setting it to what it was/is).

Comment: currently i'm using the second method, do you know why i does not update is there an error i overlooked?

Comment: i did update the $data array and removed the array from the update but it still don't work

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->db->_error_message(), $this->db->affected_rows())` give back? After the `update` call

Comment: please read through the documentation: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update#updating-data, either you use the `$this->where()` or set the 3rd parameter in the `update()` function, but not both

Comment: i did the var_dump and got this message:An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::_error_message()

Filename: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI_web_tuts/application/models/Database.php

Line Number: 44

Backtrace:

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI_web_tuts/application/controllers/Page.php
Line: 59
Function: updateRecords

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI_web_tuts/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: update i read the documentation and i used only the $this->db->update('Users',$data). Bu now i have a new problem when i update it changes all the entries with the new value, when i hover over the update link it shows: localhost/CI_web_tuts/page/updatedata?id=5. with all the entries it shows the correct id, Can you please help me